# Drop and create View behavior in vbs file

Tags: sql, vbscript, asp-classic, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-view

Hi there I am having some odd behavior with a view (sqlserver 2008 r2)

Here is the code in the file (ASP or VBS file same behavior):

```
    strsql = " USE [DBName]" & _
         " GO " & _
         " IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tblName]')) " & _
         " DROP VIEW [dbo].[viewName] " & _
         " GO "
         conn.execute(strsql)
```

In my log file I get no error bu the script does not run. When I print the paste the strsql value to the log file and paste into SQL Management console and check query I get 'Incorrect syntax near 'GO' . Since the statement is one long string I reformat it like this and it works without issue:

```
  USE [DBNAme] 
  GO  
  IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].    [viewName]'))  
  DROP VIEW [dbo].[viewName]  
  GO
```

What am I missing here, I'm sure it obvious.... Can someone post an example of how they are running a create view in an ASP or VBS file? Note. All my CREATE Table, ALTER table etc statements are working fine. Its just the view im having trouble with

Thanking you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `& _` it should be `&_`, changing this should correct the error.

On a second note for each of the lines you have put `" SQL CODE HERE`", does removing the space at the start of each quote make a difference i.e. `"SQL CODE HERE`"`? (Not sure on this)

Comment: Thank you for your input but no neither of your suggestions make any difference.  FYI the forsi one about &_ is not necessary. All of the SQL in the VBS file is constructed like this, only the view related queries fail in the way I have explained above.  Any other ideas.  Anyone???

Comment: I still have not figured this out.  How can I make this view execute in a VBS file?

Comment: It was a permissions issue.  The log file was not promoting an sort of error/indication of this. problem is now sorted